# Is there any alternative for System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Exists

Tags: c#, asp.net

The `System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Exists` always return false if i am giving a UNC like this `\\192.168.0.33\Others (F)`.

and it occurs only when I run from the installed application, otherwise it will return true if the path is true.

Comment: Try the wrapper class in my answer below, it should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access UNC file, you need to first connect to the network location by providing credentials and opening the connection to the network share, after that you can run DirectoryInfo.Exists

Look into P/Invoke to WNetAddConnection2 / NetUseAdd and pass the username/password- then you should be able to access the file / folder info.

Edit:

Try this class I made to connect to UNC paths:
http://www.mediafire.com/?77ae4ratoqa7s4b

Comment: Thank you.I can write files to tat network path through my application. Still i need to get creditnals to check that path exist or not???

Comment: No if you are able to write, then you should be able to get the Directory info.

Comment: But you say, "it only occurs when i run from installed application" - i'm not clear as to what the two scenarios are...You mean when you are debugging the application from Visual studio it runs fine, but once you install the application then DirectoryInfo.Exits does not return true? If that's the case it seems like the user credentials are different when running from inside visual studio vs installed.

Comment: When the application is installed, then also you are able to write files to the network share but are not able to read? It also might be the case, that you do have correct permission to write to one of the directories on the network share, but you don't have read or write permission to the directory you are trying to check if it exists.

Comment: when i debugging the application, it work fine.How can i check user creditinals  are different when running from inside visual studio vs installed?

Comment: You can check by, right clicking on the taskbar and running Task Manager...under processes tab you can see the Image Name (your application exe name )  in the username colum you can see the credentials of the user under which the application is running

Comment: Hey one more doubt .the path i want to access is  like this-->\\192.168.0.33\Others (F).-- then what is domain and path for your wrapper calss

Comment: domain : 192.168.0.33 , Path: \\192.168.0.33\Others (F)   - Provided the username/password you are providing is a user on 192.168.0.33, domain is basically the active directory domain name or if the computer is not part of active directory then the computer name of which you are providing username and password.

Comment: ONe more doubt. I added your wrapper class cs file to my sloution. How can i give reference to that cs file, so that i can create an object to access those functions

Answer (score 1):

It should work. My guess is that the account that your code is running under doesn't have access to the UNC path.

Answer (score 1):

See [How Can I Determine if a Folder Exists on a Computer?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/08/19/how-can-i-determine-if-a-folder-exists-on-a-computer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.IO.Directory.Exists()`.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Thanks!