# Directory.Exists(@"\\SERVERIP\aFolder\bFolder"); always returns false

Tags: c#, string, path, asp.net-mvc-5

The following path always returns `false`:

```
Directory.Exists(@"\\SERVERIP\aFolder\bFolder");
// where SERVERIP is the server-IP which is being accessed using Impersonation
```

After debugging the code, it places `double-slashes` in the `Debugger`.

I have accessed the above file path without the `@` and `double-quotes` in `WindowsExplorer`.

What am I doing wrong?

[ The code will run on a `network` ]

Comment: Do you have access to the share? Works fine here.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Yes @PatrickHofman , i have access to it and have opened it in the Windows Explorer, as already posted

Comment: Doesn't this work from Visual Studio or another machine? How did you test this?

Comment: I have tested it from Visual Studio @PatrickHofman

Comment: Make sure that the account under which you are running your web application has access to this network share. If you are running your application from IIS, it can be configured to use a different application pool identity.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov , i am using the Administrator Account of the NETWORK, which has access to all directories.

Comment: Thanks All, i have got to the root cause. The source path was picking it from DRIVE:PROGRAMFILES/IISEXPRESS because of why the Exception came. Thanks All, really its very good to find the solution. Some one please post the Answer so that i accept it @PatrickHofman

Comment: @MalikAsif I would suggest you post the answer [your self](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and accept it. Or suggest an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34548233/edit). btw,It was throwing an `exception` or returning `false` for `Directory.Exists`?

Comment: It was returning false @student [ it was, slip of tongue :-P ]........ I solved it using the Server.MapPath( ~FolderInProject/Filename.Extension );

Comment: @MalikAsif - You can update my answer or add your own to close this question for helping future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be in the `paths-`[Source/Destinations] (both or one of it[source/destination] might be causing the problem) due to the `default-paths` used by `Visual-Studio`.  So let me explain how to check wether the paths are `correct/incorrect` step by step.

---

**Configuring ** SOURCE-PATH** **:

Some times this path `DRIVE:\ProgramFiles\IISExpress` (or some other path depending on the installation location of IIS) gets concatenated with the `SOURCE-PATH` you give in the `input` To solve this problem, follow/verify these steps:

- Ensure that the `SOURCE-PATH` or `File` you are using is in the `Project-Folder`
- To Access the `SOURCE-PATH` or `File`. Always use this path/way:

```
// 1. SOURCE-PATH + fileName with Extension<br> 
Server.MapPath("~\FolderInsideProjectFolder\", "fileName.extension");
```

---

**Configuring ** DESTINATION-PATH (to a Mapped-NETWORK)** **:

This path creates a problem if the path you entered has some words `mispelled` OR if you don't have access to the specified `Server-IP[DestinationServerIP]`. To solve this problem, follow/verify these steps:

- Before Accessing the `DESTINATION-PATH` or `File` , ensure that the IP-Address you are referring to is Accessible to the Account under which your Application-code is running.

  - To learn how to run Applications under an Account. See [Impersonization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118.aspx)
- To Access the `DESTINATION-PATH` or `File`. Always use this path/way:

```
// 2. DESTINATION-PATH + fileName with Extension
@"\\SERVERIP\aFolder\bFolder" + "fileName.extension";
```

---

**NOTE:**
Remember that the `SOURCE-PATH` can be checked if it (exists/does not exist) by addressing its Fully-Qualified-Address and in that case, it will return `true` if it exists (The full-path that windows-explorer shows you in the `Address Bar (Windows-Explorer)` like `DRIVE:/....../`

**EXTRA-INFORMATION: (as it was the basic INTENSION)**

One line instruction to `Copy` the file from `local-system` → `networked-mapped drive/path` is:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(
     Server.MapPath("~\FolderInsideProjectFolder\", "fileName.extension"), 
     @"\\SERVERIP\aFolder\bFolder" + "fileName.extension" 
     [, true ] // Optional if you want the file to be over-written or not
);
```

Please inform, if any thing still is not cleared (but after some nice searching   ☋   ☛ )

Answer (score 1):

Many a times I have seen file (or directory) access problems when the user (a human, system user such as IIS_IUSR or an application) lacks required privileges.

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4182172/2404470) where the [asker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461561/null-pointer) is facing **similar problem**, I believe that [this](http://www.mediafire.com/download/77ae4ratoqa7s4b/NetworkFolder.cs) *may* help you.

Let us know, if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your sharings and support

Comment: @MalikAsif I'm sorry, I wasn't on line. You can share your *useful* edit and [anyone](http://stackoverflow.com/users) can accept it.

Comment: @Malik:  I am just about to reject your edit.  You should enter the edit as a separate answer.  1.  Your edit is not about clarifying student's answer (which a good and useful answer, and somebody else who comes searching for this problem is quite likely to find that it is the solution to their problems).  Your edit is about a completely different answer.  2.  It is perfectly permissible to answer your own question (and to accept that answer).

Comment: I rejected your answer as "should have been a reply", somebody else has rejected it as "conflicts with author's intent".

Comment: Oh, on accepting your own reply: You don't get the reputation bonus for writing the accepted reply if you do that.  You can't give *yourself* reputation (for obvious reasons).

Comment: Thanks @MartinBonner to guide me. :-)