# System.IO.Directory.Exists returns false when directory exists

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

The following code throws an exception preventing a website from displaying:

```
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(newPath))
        {
            throw new System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException();
        }
```

The newPath variable is a string of the format \\IPADDR\QA\FileAttachments.

The directory can be accessed in either Windows Explorer or Windows PowerShell (running as administrator).

I suspect it is a permissions or security problem, how can I check this?

What are the other possible problems that could generate an fake false?

This code works on another server accessing the exact same folder.

Edit - corrected the string format.

Comment: my guess is that the string is not in that form - that its \ are not there. You can easily find out by running sysinternals procmon and watching what the app does

Comment: @pm100 The Visual studio debugger shows it as \\\\IPADDR\\QA\\FileAttachments. I'll look into procmon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative for System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Exists for UNCs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182172/).

Comment: @DourHighArch Not UNC code. The code base is 6 years old.

Comment: `\\IPADDR\QA\FileAttachments` is an UNC, and they were around 6 years ago.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. These issues are almost always typos. Also please show a explorer window **clearly** showing that folder open (with the full path visible).

Comment: I suspect a permissions issue as well, catch the exception and that should tell you.

Answer (score 0):

As Dour High Arch pointed out this is probably a duplicate of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182172/is-there-any-alternative-for-system-io-directoryinfo-exists).

The problem was solved by changing the application pool user to be the administrator of the server.